# Some issues about manually filter range

Tags: vba, excel

I have been puzzled by this issue two days After I manually filtered it ,I cannot get the filtered range using

**`Set areaRng = Sheet1.ListObjects("table_area").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`**

Some one please help.

Comment: Assuming that you have a ListObject (aka *structured*) table on sheet1 named **table_area** and you are not trying to use a code name from another workbook then this should work. What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply?

```
Dim rTbl As Range
Set rTbl = Range("table_area").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

**table_area** refers to the **table name**.

Comment: I Tested it and its not including the Header Row.

Comment: My apologies. You are indeed correct. I think it's time I took a ListObject table refresher course.

Comment: Yes you are right ,I found out that there is something wrong with my further random select method ,thank you very much!